# Is it possible to view which permission set or profile grants access to an object?

Tags: soql, query, permissions

For example, I would like to know which permission set grants at least read access to an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to query the [ObjectPermissions object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_objectpermissions.htm) without the Tooling API:

> Represents the enabled object permissions for the parent PermissionSet. This object is available in API version 24.0 and later.
>
> To grant a user access to an object, associate an ObjectPermissions record with a PermissionSet that’s assigned to a user. ObjectPermissions records are only supported in PermissionSet, not in Profile.

So a query would look like this:

```
SELECT PermissionsRead, Parent.Name
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE PermissionsRead = true
AND SobjectType = 'sbaa__Approval__c'
```

And it might return a list with not only permission sets names, but also some permission sets that have ids starting with `X00e`, which indicate that the permission is actually inherited from a profile record instead.